# Dual simplex method infeasible

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

I must solve that set of inequalities (maximization):
$$2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 \le 9$$
$$5/2x_1 +  10/3x_2 + 6x_3 \gt 10 $$
$$x_1 \ge 1$$
$$x_1 \le 2$$
$$x_3 \le 2$$
$$\text{max } 5/2x_1 + 10/3x_2 + 6x_3$$

It is a one of step in branch and bound method. As you can see expression which should be maximized is same as one of the inequality. When I try to solve this using dual simplex method it break when all ratio (domain/{row_with_more_negative_rhs}) equals 0. Then i am a beginner in linear programming so should I deal with it on different way?  I try to follow examples and docs from internet but it doesn't help me.

That is part of Cutting Stock Problem solver.

**EDIT**
Simplex table:
$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccccccc|c}
      2&3&4&1&0&0&0&0&9\\
      5/2&10/3&6&0&-1&0&0&0&{10+\lambda}\\
      1&0&0&0&0&-1&0&0&1\\
      1&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&2\\
     0&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&2\\
\hline
     5/2&10/3&6&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

$\lambda \in (0,1]$

Comment: Can you show us your simplex tableaux?

Comment: @GNUSupporter I extend my question

Comment: You can't use dual simplex here.  The tableaux is neither feasible nor optimal.

Comment: @GNUSupporter, thanks for reply, but i have one more question - not dual simplex, so which method i can use? Two phase simplex?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Thank you, i will try two phase method.